# How to access an ical file from a remote url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, icalendar

I'm not a javascript developer, so this might be a dumb question, but I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere so I'm hoping someone might be able to help me.

I'm currently working on a personal project to help build up my resume and build up some web development experience, and part of that entails accessing a publicly available google calendar as an ical, and then parsing out some useful information in my code.

An example url is like this: https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

I've tried to use an xmlHttpGet request in my code like so

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}

var a = httpGet("https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics");
```

But this doesn't seem to work. What is the best way to fetch an ical file from a url like this, and get it so that I can easily interact with its contents and parse information from it?

Sidenote: I am aware that libraries exist to parse ical to json already, however, I'm moreso doing this for the learning experience so I'd like to try writing the parsing code on my own.

Comment: You can't. It's against browser cross domain policy.

Comment: If you have control over the webserver that delivers your js you can define a reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to load it through your own server. Here is an example with php:

```php
<?php
// Function to fetch the ICS content from the given URL
function fetchICSContent($url) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $icsContent = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $icsContent;
}

// URL of the ICS file
$icsURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics;

// Fetching the ICS content
$icsContent = fetchICSContent($icsURL);

// Output the ICS content
echo $icsContent;
```

Or with Node:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

// Function to fetch the ICS content from the given URL
async function fetchICSContent(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch ICS content from URL: ${url}`);
    }
    return await response.text();
}

// URL of the ICS file
const icsURL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/en.usa%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics";

// Fetching the ICS content
fetchICSContent(icsURL)
    .then(icsContent => {
        // Output the ICS content
        console.log(icsContent);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Of course you need a backend to do either one of these.